# Is there a way to see if a control is off screen and not drawn?

Tags: android

I have a app where on very small screens the buttommost textview is not drawn (it's off the screen).
Is there a way to see if it is off the screen?

Comment: Do you want to do the check in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is actually a pretty nice tool you can use called [HierarchyViewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer)
This will give you all kinds of good information like how your views are laid out, the specs for each one, and how long it takes to draw.

> The Hierarchy Viewer application allows you to debug and optimize your
>   user interface. It provides a visual representation of the layout's
>   View hierarchy (the View Hierarchy window) and a magnified view of the
>   display (the Pixel Perfect window).

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help, I wanted to do it at run time, so I could then chnage the ui if some things where not drawn,

Comment: Android does not support hot swapping of code. So there is no way your able to change the UI and have it updated instantly without reinstalling. And the HViewer is a run time tool, there is no way for it to statically analyze your views more than the graphical editor in Eclipse does.